# My python program freezes in the middle without any exceptions or errors , the same screen remains for hours without changing

Tags: python, pandas, loops, memory, freeze

So, I have a python3 program that has one main loop and 3 inner loops (try block, list creation, cleaning)
So within the main loop the processes are fetching data => cleaning it => extracting useful information => storing it in dataframe => repeat.

So it all happens within this, lets say the loop is supposed to run for 140 iterations when it reaches around 50-60 it freezes ( at times at 30-40) and it never moves across. The same screen remains no error whatsoever! What's causing this situation & how can i snap out of it?

Comment: My guess is that it is caused by something in the code that you wrote, but I can't tell you unless I see the code.

Comment: Hi , but the code stops randomly , attimes it completes and attimes it freezes in the very beginning its doing the same action every single time...on the same data...